# How to make user defined / explicit colorscale and legend in plotly?

Tags: r, colors, plotly, legend

I have a dataset subsetted by month. However, when I graph each subset, the colorscale and range of legend are all different. How can I explicitly define this, so that it's consistent across all subsets?

So in the example below, I'd like the colorscale and range of legend to be the same for the unfiltered dataset and the filtered one.

[github link to dataset](https://github.com/darrenkeeley/weather-map)

```
#original dataset. I want to construct the legend with this
weather <- read.csv("weather2_rmse.csv") %>% 
  mutate(date_of_forecast = as.Date(date_of_forecast))

#filtered. I want to construct the points with this
data <- filter(weather, date_of_forecast == "2015-02-01")

weather_map <- function(data) {

  # change default color scale title
  m <- list(colorbar = list(title = ""))

  # geo styling
  g <- list(
    scope = 'north america',
    showland = TRUE,
    landcolor = toRGB("grey83"),
    subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
    countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
    showlakes = TRUE,
    lakecolor = toRGB("white"),
    showsubunits = TRUE,
    showcountries = TRUE,
    resolution = 50,
    projection = list(
      type = 'conic conformal',
      rotation = list(lon = -100)
    ),
    lonaxis = list(
      showgrid = TRUE,
      gridwidth = 0.5,
      range = c(-140, -55),
      dtick = 5
    ),
    lataxis = list(
      showgrid = TRUE,
      gridwidth = 0.5,
      range = c(20, 60),
      dtick = 5
    )
  )

  #the plotly part
  p <- plot_geo(data, lat = ~latitude, lon = ~longitude, color = ~rmse) %>%
    add_markers(
      text = ~paste(data$rmse, "RMSE"), hoverinfo = "text"
    ) %>%
    layout(title = 'Average RMSE of MaxTemp Forecasts by Month<br>xxxxxxxxxx', geo = g)
  p
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example this way: Define a scale, e.g.

```
scl = list(c(0, "rgb(0, 0, 255)"), list(1, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"))
```

(You can also add more values, this is based on quantiles AFAIK. So setting it like this

```
scl = list(c(0, "rgb(0, 0, 255)"), list(0.1, "rgb(0, 0, 255)"),
           c(0.1, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"), list(1, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"))
```

Will make the first 10% of your values be blue, the remainder green.

Then, modify your plot call e.g. like this:

```
  p <- plot_geo(data) %>%
    add_markers(y = ~latitude, x = ~longitude,
                mode = "markers", type = "scatter", 
                marker = list(color = ~rmse,
                              colorscale = scl,
                              cauto = FALSE,
                              colorbar = list(title=""),
                              cmax = 15,
                              cmin = 0)) %>%
    layout(title = 'Average RMSE of MaxTemp Forecasts by Month<br>xxxxxxxxxx', geo = g)
  p
```

By setting the exact limits with `cmax` and `cmin` you should have the same scale across subplots

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the functionality I was looking for! I'm curious, when defining scl, was there a particular reason for alternating between c and list? Just c also worked for me.

Comment: No particular reason, just preference :) Glad it helped!